# Select records where among at least one of a chosen set of fields are populated

Tags: sql, postgresql

In table `TEST`, how can I select rows where one or more fields of `col_a`, `col_b`, ... `col_n` are populated? So, for example, if only `col_n` is populated, I still want that record.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not null` in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from test
where col_a is not null or col_b is not null or col_c is not null;
```

Comment: But doesn't this mean if all of them are null, it will still select the record?

Comment: @AlanH . . . If all of them are null, then each expression will be false.  `or` of a bunch of `false` values is `false` so the row will not be selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the coalesce function.  It'll return the first non-null value, so will return null if and only if all fields are null.

```
select t.*
from test
where coalesce(col_a,col_b,col_c) is not null
```

[Coalesce documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)